# ¿Qué significa que un elemento este en el flujo normal?

Tags: html, css

> Normal flow is how the browser lays out HTML pages by default when you
>   do nothing to control page layout.
>
> Everything in normal flow has a value of display, used as the default
>   way that elements they are set on behave.

Hasta aquí comprendo que el flujo normal es el como los navegadores colocan los elementos por defecto, siempre usando la propiedad `display`.

Luego me confundo un poco con lo que sigue

> The display property — Standard values such as block, inline or
>   inline-block can change how elements behave in normal flow

Cambiando el valor de `display` solo cambio como el elemento se comporta en el flujo normal pero no sale del flujo normal.

> When you use CSS to create a layout, you are moving the elements away
>   from the normal flow

Cuando  utilizo `display: flex` estoy creando un layout, de acuerdo con la cita de arriba (justo arriba de este párrafo) ademas yo movería al elemento del flujo normal.

Entonces con `display` solo cambio como la caja se comporta en el flujo normal no lo muevo del flujo normal a como da a entender la segunda cita, entonces no se que es el flujo normal...porque cuando toca explicar la propiedad `position` en el articulo que estoy leyendo,dice que `position`  causa que el elemento salga completamente del flujo normal. Pero no se que es exactamente estar en el flujo normal. ¿Es el flujo normal cuando los elementos se colocan de acuerdo a la propiedad `display`? entonces decir que usar `position` saca al elemento del flujo normal porque ya no obedece a la propiedad `display` tiene sentido pero no se, estoy confundido. ayuda, por favor.

Bueno las citas las saque de aquí, que es donde estoy aprendiendo css:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction

Comment: position es como se posiciona el elemento dentro de su contenedor. Static es lo normal, que es dentro del flujo. Absolute, te permite ponerlo en un lugar fijo. Y relative es relativo a su posición static. Cuando position no es static, se dice que está posicionado. Y cuando está posicionado podes usar top bottom left y right para setear la posición.

Answer (score 0):

Te respondo debajo de cada pregunta para llevar un orden.

> ¿Es el flujo normal cuando los elementos se colocan de acuerdo a la
>   propiedad display? entonces decir que usar `position` saca al elemento
>   del flujo normal porque ya no obedece a la propiedad `display` tiene
>   sentido pero no se, estoy confundido. ayuda, por favor.**

**El flujo normal es la forma en la que el navegador coloca inicialmente los elementos en la pantalla.
De hecho de acuerdo a la **w3c** el flujo normal son los elementos siendo colocados como cajas de bloque o cajas en linea.**

> Boxes in the normal flow belong to a formatting context, which may be
>   block or inline, but not both simultaneously.

**Cuando alteras este comportamiento estas sacando a los elementos del flujo normal**

Answer (score 0):

Las etiquetas HTML cuando son renderizadas en el navegador siguen 2 reglas para su disposición:

- **`block`**
- **`inline`**

Donde la primera genera que los elementos:

- Se acomoden de extremo a extremo y queden apilados uno sobre otro

Mientras que los elementos en línea

- Quedan en fila uno después del otro

Para caso práctico debes recordar que a los elementos en bloque si les puedes declarar un ancho y un alto mientras que para los elementos en línea no.

**Caso 1**

Entonces una web con una etiqueta de naturaleza bloque y 2 de naturaleza inline se verían así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Nota*

> Pero esta disposición de los elementos que da el navegador por lo ya antes mencionado se puede perfectamente modificar si a los elementos que son bloque los volvemos en línea y/o al revés.

**Caso 2**

Por ejemplo al primer elemento lo volvemos en línea y a los 2 restantes en bloque lucirían algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Nota*

> Entonces con esa clave y valor facilmente modificamos el flujo regular que dichas etiquetas tienen.

**Caso 3**

De hecho con **`display: inline-block;`** poseemos una tercer opción para disponer elementos y si para nuestro ejemplo se lo aplicamos a los elementos in linea que son los de color tomate quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos observar que si modificamos esta propiedad de los elementos si alteramos el flujo regular que tienen en su acomodo pues dependiendo cual de las 3 según sea el caso apliquemos entonces pueden pasar de fila a columna.

Como referencias importantes de leer:

- [css display](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display)